# Macbook Pro 13 Retina Trusty: suspend and resume doesn't work correctly

Tags: suspend, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Macbook 13'' (with retina display) successfully.

The only problem is that sometimes, when I close and then open the lid on my laptop (I have it set to suspend when closed), the screen won't turn on or flashes a few times before going black. The Apple logo on the back of the lid flashes in sync with the screen but the keyboard back-light remains on. Other times when I turn it off the screen will remain on and sometimes freeze. Also, 50% of the time when I do get it working, the network connections is off.

I have searched for other solutions and have seen similar reports but have not found a clear answer. I don't have much experience with code but have used terminal effectively.

*How should I proceed?*